# How to club observations based on variable condition

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame that is set up like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqg8S.png)

The variable, level2, is a factor variable with levels 1 to 5. I know how many observations are in each 1 to 5. However, I am wanting to club observations into the next group if they have <150 observations.

So for example, if level2 == 2 and there are only 120 observations here, I want to move these observations into level2 == 3.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Forgive my naivete, but what is "club observations"? FYI, based on the image of your data, your numeric column `exposed...` is not numeric.

Comment: So if there are only 120 observations that have a level2 that is equal 2, I want to group them with the observations that all have a level2 equal to 3 .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description,

```
l2 = levels(your_data$level2)
for(i in seq_along(l2)) {
  if(sum(your_data$level2 == i) < 150) {
    your_data$level2[your_data$level2 == i] = l2[i + 1]
  }
}
```

This assumes the final level has at least 150 observations, or at least that it will after "clubbing".

Comment: Thank you. How can I check that my new data frame made the correct changes after this loop clubbed the levels with <150 observations

Comment: You can look at the counts before and after running the code: `table(your_data$level2)`. I'd also suggest creating a small test case - make 20 rows of data where you club levels with < 5 observations. Generally a minimal reproducible example like that is nice to put in your question because it's easy to then verify that solutions actually accomplish the goal. (That's what r2evans was getting at when he asked you to share `dput(head(x))` - a few rows of data shared reproducibly.)